# Not a Valid Month in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Hi im trying to get number of rows from table using Hibernate based on start and end Date but im Getting not a Valid Month error

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();         
startDate = "13-02-02 00:00:00";
endDate = "17-02-02 00:00:00";
try{
    String hql = "select Count(*) from mytable where PERIOD_START_DATETIME between '" 
                 + startDate + "' AND '" + endDate + "'";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    long count=(long) query.uniqueResult();

    return count;
} finally{
     session.close();
}
```

This is my table description

```
Name                    NULL     TYPE
NAME                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)  
PERIOD_END_DATETIME     NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)        
PERIOD_START_DATETIME   NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)        
PROD_OFFER_TERM_TYPE_ID NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
```

Comment: Check the date format used. If it's the american M-D-Y format then 13 and 17 are not valid months.

Comment: Instead of concatenating the variables into the query, use bind variables and pass in the actual Java dates, not their string representations.

Comment: @Thomas it is YY-MM-DD mm:hh:ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the start/end times are SQL `TIMESTAMP`s in the DB, you can pass in a `Timestamp` object into the query as follows:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd");

// omitting the time part will set the time to midnight (00:00:00)
Timestamp start = new Timestamp(df.parse("13-02-02").getTime());
Timestamp end = new Timestamp(df.parse("17-02-02").getTime());

try {
    String hql = 
        "select Count(*) from mytable where PERIOD_START_DATETIME between ? AND ?";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql)
            .setTimestamp(0, start)
            .setTimestamp(1, end);

    long count = (long) query.uniqueResult();

    return count;
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: will this work if i have to pass table name at runtime as well

Comment: So you don't know the name of the table compile-time?

Comment: @Wayne when working with Hibernate you should _not_ think in table names. If anything you'd pass an _entity_ name (the name of the class or an alias). And since you're constructing the query anyways, what makes you think that wouldn't work?

Comment: i was firing query on multiple tables based on a list. I just appended the table name in String and provided timestamp as per your solution and it worked pretty smoothly thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Using string concatenation for generating SQL queries is usually a bad idea because

- it's bad for performance (causes re-parsing of the SQL statement for every execution)
- it's prone to SQL injection attacks

HQL supports bind variables / prepared statements, so this should work:

```
String hql = "select Count(*) from mytable where PERIOD_START_DATETIME between :startdate AND :enddate ";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("startdate", startDate);
query.setParameter("enddate", endDate);
```

(where startDate and endDate are actual `java.sql.Timestamp` values, not strings).

Comment: Date values wont work as i have stored date in Db as TimeStamp which takes different formats based on Language .

Comment: The DB doesn't *store* timestamps in different formats based on language - the only time formats come into play is when you *convert* your timestamp to / from a string.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you actually pass date values in your query.
You can use the to_date function where you specify the format of the date, as it is represented in the string.

```
select Count(*) 
from mytable 
where PERIOD_START_DATETIME between to_date(startDate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND to_date(endDate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: how should i do it in Hibernate

Comment: Just as you did in your example. Add the to date function in the query you are constructing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Count(*) 
from mytable 
where PERIOD_START_DATETIME between TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP(:endDate, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```